# Rails models in subfolders and relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I organized some of my rails models in folders which I am autoloading with

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

I can use all models directly(e.g `Image.first.file_name`) but when I try to access them through relationships, e.g. `@housing.images.each do...` with `has_many: images` I get the following error

```
Unable to autoload constant Housing::HousingImage, expected /path/app/models/housing/image.rb to define it
```

How do i get rails to use my models for the relationship methods?

I'm running ruby 2.2 and rails 4.2

Answer (score 20):

Rails automatically loads models from subfolders but does expect them to have namespace.

```
/app/models/user.rb
class User
end

/app/models/something/user.rb
class Something::User
end
```

If you do not properly namespace your models in subfolders it will mess up Rails autoloader and cause errors like you see.

Remove this

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

And add the proper namespaces to your models and everything will work fine.

You can easily use namespaced models in your relationships like this:

```
class User
  has_many :photos, class_name: 'Something::Photo'
end

user.photos (will be instances of Something::Photo)
```

If you do not want to use the namespacing but split up your models for other reason, you can do that at the top-level and use other folders next to models.
By default rails loads all the folders in apps, so you could just make a folder "models2" or whatever you want to call it next to "models".
This will not have any effect on the functionality of the rails class loading.

Given your example you could then do:

```
/app
  /controllers
  /models
    for all your normal models
  /housing
    for your "housing" models
```

Like this you can directly access them at the top level namespace, no class_name settings or anything needed.

Comment: Correct, but I dont wont them namespaced, wihich is why i added the config in the first place. I also tried the class_name option with the non-namespaced class name but it didn't work either.

Comment: Within the models (or any other rails folder) you need to stick to the rails naming convention otherwise this will cause you a lot of headache. Alternatively you could split up the models folder directly (see my updated answer in a moment)

Comment: Ok, I will go with your solution, but I think the class_name option on the relationship should probably work? I will open a issue on github to investigate  further.

Comment: @ReneKoller has the github inquiry provided any proper solution? I'm facing the exact same problem now.

Comment: can I ask if this is a good praktis for ruby on rails development?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed I would recommend it, yes. But it depends on the structure of your project at the end which is the best approach